# JHipster Liquibase Warning SSL Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, liquibase, jhipster

When I make the diff of liquibase I receive a mesage about SSL connection (see bellow)

```
Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification. Jan 04, 2016 11:46:29 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
```

But I already changed every MySQL connection propertie file on JHipster files (in dev and prod) with the `&useSSL=false`. But still having the error.

Anyone know if there is another file which I have to update?

I'm using the lasted version of JHipster (3.10.0).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liquibase diff does not use JHipster application properties files, it's just something between maven and liquibase, have you changed this setting in your pom.xml?

Comment: I didn't make any change, I created 3 classes and, to persist the classes, I used the diff (but I'm facing this error)

Comment: Maybe there's a misunderstanding here, when you use liquibase diff through maven the configuration and options are in the pom.xml and in your case I think you MUST change them. See https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/pom.xml#L571-L581  otherwise clarify your use case

Comment: Yes you was right, was my mistake. After I take a time works perfecly!